# Appending a Column in INFORMATICA expression transformation

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a scenario where we are concatenating some strings and then appending it with a database column using the + operand in expression transformation

'PWC mapping '||'PWC_MAPPING_NAME'||'- session start '||TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ||'|'||+ edw_update_note

But I seem to be getting an error + operand cannot be converted to a number error.

NOTE: the same above logic works fine in SQL developer, please suggest me some solution to the above scenario

Comment: edw_update_note is the database column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Informatica expression transformation uses double pipe to concat. Pls use ||.
Pls use -
    `'PWC mapping '||'PWC_MAPPING_NAME'||'- session start '||TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ||'|'|| edw_update_note`

1. First create a lookup on the target table. Use key to pickup latest update note.
   LKP SQL will be - select MAX(key) as id, edw_update_note from target order by 1 --
2. In expression transformation call the lookup as LKP.LKP_NAME(key). Name it as lkp_edw_update_note.
3. Then create another output port as o_edw_update_note as
   'PWC mapping '||'PWC_MAPPING_NAME'||'- session start '||TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ||'|'|| lkp_edw_update_note
   Connect this port to target edw_update_note.

Comment: I have already been using || in expression, can u please give me an example for the above?

Comment: You are concatenating edw_update_note using +. Pls remove it and use expression just like answer.

Comment: we are trying to append a value with the latest value, for example, there is a column called EDW_UPDATE_NOTE which store's the data as "PWC mapping name - session start 06/22/2017 00:18:30" and later there is a change in the record, for example, today then I want the data to get stored in the column as "WC mapping name - session start 05/16/2017 00:18:30 | WC mapping name - session start 06/22/2017 00:18:30". Is there a way to achieve this logic Using expression transformation?

Comment: when there is an update then the result appears as "WC mapping name - session start 05/16/2017 00:18:30 | WC mapping name - session start 05/16/2017 00:18:30". Rather than showing as "WC mapping name - session start 05/16/2017 00:18:30 | WC mapping name - session start 06/22/2017 00:18:30".

Is there a way to achieve this logic in Informatica expression transformation?

Comment: I think i answered to your question in other thread. Basically you need to fetch old EDW_UPDATE_NOTE first by doing lookup and the concatenate. Please refer to the edited answer.